# Unittest inline data string with fixed lengh?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Is is possible for a unittest test to provide a string as input as an `inlineData` where the length is specified, but the content it random..

```
[Trait("Category", "IntegrationTest")]
        [Theory]
        public async Task TooLongString_ReturnNotOK(string myString)
{
...
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. You can simply generate a random string with a given length inside your test code.... Or select a random member of an array of strings

Comment: @ZoharPeled cant this be provided as sort of inline data?

Comment: You mean as an attribute? If so, than the answer is no. Attributes must be known at compile time, they can't change at runtime.

Comment: Why do you want random input data at all? You will have the problem that when the test fails, it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @KlausGütter random values might still be reproducible - if you're using an explicit seed for your random generator than the random sequence will be the same at every run.